# How to use inserted table in variable in insert trigger sql server?

Tags: sql-server, variables, triggers, insert

I want to use inserted table in query variable to create trigger on insert,
like this

```
SET @strTemp = 'INSERT INTO '+@LeadTable+'(service_id,
batch_no,
phone1,
userid,
tt_no
,complaint_id) 
select inserted.ProcId,''' + @szBatchName + ''',Right(inserted.Phone,11),inserted.UserId,inserted.TtNo,inserted.ComplaintId from inserted'
```

this code is not inserting data in destination table.
I want to know how to achieve this?
please help.
thank you

this is my actual code bt its not working

```
USE [LeadDTB]

alter TRIGGER [dbo].[Push_SibelRealTimeData]
on [dbo].[SibelRealTimeData]
After Insert
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @szProcId   varchar(20)
DECLARE @szUserId   varchar(50)
DECLARE @szTtNo varchar(15)
DECLARE @szComplaintId  varchar(50)
DECLARE @szPhone varchar(50)
Declare @szBatchName varchar(50)
Declare @LeadDB varchar(50)
Declare @LeadTable varchar(50)
Declare @strTemp varchar(max)
Declare @nBatchCount int
declare @szdialTime varchar(50)

CREATE TABLE #tmTable (id int,procid varchar(50),uid varchar(50),ttno varchar(50),complaintid  varchar(50),phone varchar(50))

select * into #tmTable from inserted 

select @szdialTime = DATEADD(HOUR, 1, GETDATE())

set @szBatchName = 'SIBELRT_'+CONVERT(varchar(5), right(Year(GETDATE()),2))+Convert(varchar(5),MONTH(GETDATE()))

select @LeadDB =  service_db_name from services where service_id =@szProcId

set @LeadTable = @LeadDB+'..LEAD_MASTER_' + @szProcId

SET @strTemp = 'INSERT INTO '+@LeadTable+'(
service_id,
lead_import_batch_id, 
lead_phone1,
userid,
tgs_tt_no,
lead_complaint_id
) 
select 
procid,
''' + @szBatchName + ''',
Right(phone,11),
uid,
ttno,
complaintid from #tmTable '

EXEC(@strTemp)

drop table #tmtable

END
```

this code is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
INTO   #temp
FROM   inserted

SET @strTemp = 'INSERT INTO ' + @LeadTable
               + '(service_id,
                   batch_no,
                   phone1,
                   userid,
                   tt_no,
                   complaint_id) 
select ProcId,''' + @szBatchName
               + ''',Right(Phone,11),UserId,TtNo,ComplaintId from #temp'
```

Answer (score 1):

The inserted table is not visible within the scope of the dynamic SQL statement.  You'll need to insert rows from inserted into a table variable (or temp table) and then use that in the dynamic SQL statement.  The table variable will need to be passed as a parameter to the dynamic SQL as a parameter (as should be the @szBatchName value).